# php - comparing a text box and drop down with database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get a text from textbox and a selected item from dropdown menu from users. I have develop a code but not a single code is working.

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Coupon validation Registration</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="validation.php" method="post">

<input name="boxcoupon" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 665px; 
padding:0px; margin-top: 15px; z-index: 2; position: absolute;" /><br><br>
<br><br>
<select name="dropuni" style="z-index: 1; width: 695px; padding:0px; 
position:absolute;">
<option value="Value for Item 1" title="Title for Item 1">123</option>
<option value="Value for Item 2" title="Title for Item 2">456</option>
<option value="Value for Item 3" title="Title for Item 3">789</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>

</form>  
</body> 
</html>
```

and the **validation.php**

```
?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'dbh.php';

$uboxcoupon = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['boxcoupon']);
$dropuni = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dropuni']);
$check = "SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE couponorigin = $uboxcoupon or 
droporigin = $dropuni";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $check);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {
    header("Location: index.php?login=error@");
} else {
    header("Location: register.php?login=success");
}



} else {
header("Location: index.php?login=error 2");
exit();

}   ?>
```

I always get register.php?login=error@ even if I give correct info or wrong. I have tried many ways but failed. 
where is the mistake.

Comment: Print the data in $_POST using print_r($_POST) in validation.php file

Comment: Where to print and what to print? @rakesh

Comment: what is datatype of `couponorigin` and `droporigin` in database?

Comment: both are Varchar @B.Desai

Answer (score 0):

Your `couponorigin` and `couponorigin` must be in string datatype so you need to put `'` around values. Try following.

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE couponorigin = '$uboxcoupon' or 
droporigin = '$dropuni'";
```

Also use **prepared statements** to prevent from sql injections

Comment: Is your `droporigin` strored like `Value for Item 1` , `Value for Item 2` etc on your db?

Comment: Then change option value correctly `<option value="Value for Item 1" title="Title for Item 1">123</option>` to `<option value="123" title="Title for Item 1">123</option>` and so on

Comment: echo `$check` and copy paste your query directly to mysql server and check what you are getting

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpn\validation.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpn\validation.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpn\validation.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpn\validation.php on line 7
SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE couponorigin = '' or droporigin = ''

Comment: so where `$conn` is defined?

Comment: Thanks A lot. Problem Solved :)